# Xamarin Forms ListView Row Height Incorrect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Ive been trying to sort out issues with the Row Height that gets calculated when rendering a ListView in Xamarin Forms (iOS)

Here is my XAML

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="18" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=Teaser}" TextColor="Gray" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUrl}" WidthRequest="100" Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="100" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

but here is a screenshot of how it gets rendered in the simulator

(I am binding to 10 rows of the same data, which is why each row looks the same)

[image]

As you can see, the row height isnt being correctly calculated for the row contents.

I can set a fixed RowHeight for the ListView but this isnt good because the rowheight will need to be different for different devices.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: set your_list.HasUnevenRows = true; and your_list.RowHeight = 60;

Comment: ah thanks so much. The HasUnevenRows=true fixed it (i assumed you only set it to true if the rows were uneven). I didnt set the row height as it needs to be different depending on the size of the device

Comment: Okay, i'll post as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set

```
your_list.HasUnevenRows = true;
```

and/or

```
your_list.RowHeight = 60;
```